# Identifier not found when it's not meant to be an identifier?

Tags: c++, identifier

I have defined a function called decryptionArchive() like this:

```
string decryptionArchive(char i) {

}
```

Can you create a function with a string identifier? I've search everywhere and everything I have found is about creating pointers to string data types. When I run this code:

```
string charToAdd = decryptionArchive(i[curr]);
```

Yes, I have imported string, and I am using namespace std. 'i' is a string, is that the issue? The actual error code is

```
error C3861: 'decryptionArchive': identifier not found
```

This error occurs on line 26, which is the line of the `string charToAdd = decryptionArchive(i[curr]);` which doesn't make sense to me. Any ideas? Thanks

EDIT:
Just ran this on my laptop, it works fine! What is going on here?

Comment: are all the codes is in the same file?

Comment: `decryptionArchive()` is probably defined in a different compilation unit (aka source file) than the line that calls it.    A declaration needs to be seen by the compiler in that other compilation unit before the call point.

Comment: Everything here is in the same source file.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't declare i as an array. You are treating i as  an array, yet i isn't an array.

Comment: This does make sense, but I thought this was the way you got a specific letter from a string in c++? If I defined a string and then did      *stringname*[0] I thought that would get the first letter of that string. If this is not the case, how would I go about getting a specific letter of a string?

Comment: How about you allocated memory like this.

Comment: decryptiontoAchieve(char i [80])

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string str ("Test string");
  for (unsigned i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
  {
    std::cout << str.at(i);
  }
  return 0;
}

Comment: OP said i is a string